# Installing MATE desktop environment without installing the applications

Tags: 12.04, desktop-environments, mate

I want to install MATE desktop only, without applications.

I already have apps from GNOME 3 - nautilus, file-roller, gedit. But when I `sudo apt-get install mate-core`, it asks to install caja, pluma, engrampa etc. How to avoid them?

Comment: Mate is altogether a new Desktop environment , its applications makes it a Desktop Environment , Just installing Core won't help much.

Comment: i already installed mate-core on virtualbox and it installs with caja and pluma etc. Mate-core is metapackage. I need list of packages or somethings. MATE have two commands - sudo apt-get install mate-core and sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment. But there is no logick - mate-core installs all packages...

Comment: They are interdependent , they both are needed to provide you Mate DE refer the packages [here](http://packages.mate-desktop.org/repo/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mate-desktop-environment/) ,where mate-core is meta package as you said.

Comment: OK, i understand. Caja draws desktop etc. Is there way use mate-panel only in gnome-fallback? I really love this panel, because it support custom backround. But i can't logout and shutdown, because it use mate-session-manager. How to force mate-panel to use gnome-session manager?

Answer (score 5):

https://wiki.mate-desktop.org/download#ubuntu offers these installation choices:

```
# This will install the base packages required for a minimal MATE desktop
sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment-core

# This will install the complete MATE desktop
sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment

# This will install the complete MATE desktop including a few extras
sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment-extras
```

Comment: Update: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-core ubuntu-mate-desktop` to install "the complete MATE Desktop Environment as well as LightDM and numerous other applications to provide a full and well rounded desktop" according to https://wiki.mate-desktop.org/download#ubuntu

Comment: 1. Install the MATE Desktop Environment with `sudo apt install mate-desktop-environment`
 2. If you want some extras `sudo apt install mate-desktop-environment-extras`

https://wiki.mate-desktop.org/introduction/installation/

Answer (score 1):

Do this command / in the theminal if you have the mate ppa aredy added.

```
sudo apt-get install mate-panel
```

Comment: let me now by replying to this comment if that doesn't work then I will do more and explain more!

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Install the whole Mate Desktop Environment.
2. Track the (additional) applications which will be installed together with it.
3. Remove these applications after the MATE installation .(not all of them because some of them are likely to be dependent).
4. (Re)associate (some of) the applications from Gnome to be the default again.

That will need some effort from you. But you should keep in mind that installing a Desktop Environment is installing its applications (of course, you can change some of them, but almost never all of them). That is a whole experience. Unless you install a minimal WM like fluxbox, openbox, etc; there you could fully personalize your applications customization experience.