# System tray information disappeared

Tags: 14.04, system-tray

Last week the system tray disappeared on my laptop running 14.04 Mate, meaning all information and menus in the top right corner: time and date, network, sound volume, shutdown etc. I remember that some process crashed and I may have clicked the wrong button when that happened, resulting in this process not starting anymore.

How can I get this back?

Comment: What happens if you open a terminal and issue the command `mate-panel` ?

Answer (score 1):

same thing happened to me. here's what you can do: right click the panel and then
"add to panel", select "notification area"

Comment: Good tip, but right clicking does not result in anything. Only if I right-click on the shortcut-icons for applications, do I see options. On the empty right side of the top bar nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see if it exists and where with `which mate-panel` which should return `/usr/bin/mate-panel`.

You can reinstall it with `sudo apt-get install mate-panel`

This command will also error and tell you if you already have the latest version.

If `mate-panel` is running you can right click the panel to add missing components to the panel (clock, etc, etc.)

Comment: I tried to reinstall using your command. Nothing happens - the app is already installed. So I removed mate-panel and then tried to reinstall. Removing worked, reinstalling not. So I'm using Unity now, which works OK but is not my preferred desktop.

Comment: Can you clarify? I'm not sure why you are telling me you removed mate-panel (Nowhere in my answer was this suggested) It sounds like you uninstalled the entire MATE DE (Desktop Environment) and Installed Unity DE. Is this what you are talking about? If so this should be a new question as it's beyond the scope of the Ubuntu Mate Panel. You may find this useful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/180872/installing-mate-desktop-environment-without-installing-the-applications

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for months and I just fixed it. think I had some dodgey applets running. So I reinstalled mate-panel and then killed the process. When I killed the process it gave me a message about some rogue applets running and asked if I wanted to delete them. I said yes and haven't had a problem since:

```
sudo apt-get remove mate-panel
sudo apt-get install mate-panel
sudo killall mate-panel
```